# Create a calendar event/meeting for multiple days, not repeating

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I was wondering if this is something that is possible within Outlook. I've searched for this option within Outlook and on Google with no results. What I want to do is be able to send just 1 invite, but for multiple days on the calendar.

My schedule for work changes every week because I have to come in early/late every week and the days are random because of my 2nd job.

For example, week 1, I could be coming in at 8am instead of 7, or come in at 6 instead of 8am, and the days are different. I get my schedule 1 month in advance so I send out calendar invites pretty much 30 times. The people I invite are getting 30 emails for each month. The pattern doesn't repeat so I can't set it to repeat.

Is there a way to send out 1 invite for multiple days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps :)

"Unfortunately Outlook doesn't have the capability for creating this type of meeting request, but you can do nearly the same thing by creating the meetings in the calendar, then send the invitees a message with each of the meetings attached and instructions to choose the meeting they want to attend."

Reference:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/i-want-to-send-a-meeting-invite-with-multiple-time/52c52de9-9786-44e5-b32e-8b63382b5e35

https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/create-a-pick-a-meeting-request/

Comment: Thanks for the information. Sucks that this feature isn't something we're able to do. Seems like it would be a common thing to do